# How to raise warning if return value is disregarded?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, static-analysis

I'd like to see all the places in my code (C++) which disregard return value of a function. How can I do it - with gcc or static code analysis tool?

Bad code example:

```
int f(int z) {
    return z + (z*2) + z/3 + z*z + 23;
}


int main()
{
  int i = 7;
  f(i); ///// <<----- here I disregard the return value

  return 1;
}
```

Please note that:

- it should work even if the function and its use are in different files
- **free** static check tool

Comment: This will print a lot of warnings if you use `printf` for example.

Comment: The "probable" reason it cannot be enforced via the command line is that if you have a valid reason to disregard a result, then you would end up with the need to allocate an "unused variable" which would generate a warning. For example, you certainly don't want `T& operator=(T rhs);` to force you to catch the result ;)

Comment: @Matthieu M: You don't need to allocate a dummy variable when  you want to ignore the return value of a function.  Simply cast the function call to void, as in `(void) function_returning_a_val();`.  When reading the code, this also makes it clearer that you are intentionally ignoring the return value.

Comment: `[[nodiscard]]` in C++17.

Comment: Since this looks like the oldest and most upvoted question on this topic I added an update answer covering C++17.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You want GCC's `warn_unused_result` attribute:

```
#define WARN_UNUSED __attribute__((warn_unused_result))

int WARN_UNUSED f(int z) {
    return z + (z*2) + z/3 + z*z + 23;
}

int main()
{
  int i = 7;
  f(i); ///// <<----- here i disregard the return value
  return 1;
}
```

Trying to compile this code produces:

```
$ gcc test.c
test.c: In function `main':
test.c:16: warning: ignoring return value of `f', declared with
attribute warn_unused_result
```

You can see this in use in the [Linux kernel](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.32/include/linux/compiler-gcc3.h#L16); they have a `__must_check` macro that does the same thing; looks like you need GCC 3.4 or greater for this to work.  Then you will find that macro used in kernel header files:

```
unsigned long __must_check copy_to_user(void __user *to,
                                        const void *from, unsigned long n);
```

Comment: Works fine in a header file for me.  I put a function prototype with WARN_UNUSED in a new file lib.h and then included that from test.c and got the same warning.  Also note this is how the Linux kernel does it.

Comment: More details about this attribute can be found in official gcc docs. `6.33.1 Common Function Attributes
---------------------------------` . 
Install `gcc-doc` apt package for easy navigation in gcc docs. Once you have it, simply use info to read `$ info gcc` and in index search for `warn_unused_result`.

Answer (score 19):

For C++17 the answer to this question changes since we now have the [[[nodiscard]]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) attribute. Covered in [[dcl.attr.nodiscard]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.attr.nodiscard):

> The attribute-token nodiscard may be applied to the declarator-id in a function declaration or to the declaration of a class or enumeration. It shall appear at most once in each attribute-list and no attribute-argument-clause shall be present.

and

> [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct [[nodiscard]] error_info { /* ... */ };
> error_info enable_missile_safety_mode();
> void launch_missiles();
> void test_missiles() {
>   enable_missile_safety_mode(); // warning encouraged
>   launch_missiles();
> }
> error_info &foo();
> void f() { foo(); }             // warning not encouraged: not a nodiscard call, because neither
>                                 // the (reference) return type nor the function is declared nodiscard
> ```
>
> — end example ]

So modifying your example ([see it live](https://godbolt.org/g/7y61uM)):

```
[[nodiscard]] int f(int z) {
    return z + (z*2) + z/3 + z*z + 23;
}


int main()
{
  int i = 7;
  f(i); // now we obtain a diagnostic

  return 1;
}
```

We now obtain a diagnostic with both gcc and clang e.g.

```
warning: ignoring return value of function declared with 'nodiscard' attribute [-Wunused-result]
  f(i); // now we obtain a diagnostic
  ^ ~
```

Answer (score 10):

As far as I'm aware there is no GCC option to give this warning. However, if you are interested in specific functions, you can tag them with an attribute:

```
int fn() __attribute__((warn_unused_result));
```

which would give a warning if the return value of fn() was not used. Caveat: I've never used this feature myself.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this handy template to do it at run-time.

Instead of returning an error code (e.g. HRESULT) you return a return_code<HRESULT>, which asserts if it goes out of scope without the value being read. It's not a static analysis tool, but it's useful none the less.

```
class return_value
{
public:
  explicit return_value(T value)
    :value(value), checked(false)
  {
  }

  return_value(const return_value& other)
    :value(other.value), checked(other.checked)
  {
    other.checked = true;
  }

  return_value& operator=(const return_value& other)
  {
    if( this != &other ) 
    {
      assert(checked);
      value = other.value;
      checked = other.checked;
      other.checked = true;
    }
  }

  ~return_value(const return_value& other)
  {
    assert(checked);
  }

  T get_value()const {
    checked = true;
    return value;
  }

private:
  mutable bool checked;
  T value;
};
```

Comment: It's a nice idea.  Unfortunately it violates the "destructors mustn't throw" principle: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.3, but maybe that'd be acceptable for a "check all returns" testing mode (there's probably no need for the check in a final release build).

Comment: I've seen implementations that use the most significant bit of the error code instead of the `bool`.

Answer (score 4):

Any static analysis code (e.g. [PC-Lint](http://www.gimpel.com/)) should be able to tell you that.  For PC-Lint, I know that this is the case.

Answer (score 4):

a static analyzer will do the work for you, but if your code base is more then trivial   prepare to be overwhelmed ;-)

Answer (score 4):

A static analyzer will be your best bet here.  We use Coverity here, but there are [free tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis) available that you can use as well.

If you need a quick-and-dirty solution and you have a Linux-style shell handy, you can try something like:

```
grep -rn "function_name" * | grep -v "="
```

That will find every line that references the specified function but does not contain an "=".  You can get a lot of false positives (and potentially some false negatives) but if you don't have a static analyzer it's a decent place to start.

Answer (score 2):

The classic 'lint' program used to be very voluble about functions that returned a value that was ignored.  The trouble was, many of those warnings were unwanted - leading to excessive noise in the lint output (it was picking up bits of fluff that you wanted it to ignore).  That's probably why GCC doesn't have a standard warning for it.

The other issue - the flip side - is "how do you suppress the warning when you know you are ignoring the result but really don't care".  The classic scenario for that is:

```
if (signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN) != SIG_IGN)
    signal(SIGHUP, sighandler);
```

You care about the first result from `signal()`; you know that the second will be SIG_IGN (since you just set it to that).  To get away from the warnings, I sometimes use some variant on:

```
if ((old = signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN)) != SIG_IGN)
    old = signal(SIGHUP, sighandler);
```

This assigns to `old` both times.  You can follow that with 'assert(old == SIG_IGN)'.

Comment: Actually, the typical way of saying "no, I really don't care about the return value" is with a cast to `void`, e.g. `(void)printf("Hello, world!\n");`  Even at the highest warning level, no warning will be emitted for this with the explicit cast to void.

Comment: Yes, the '`(void)`' cast works...it looks ugly in the code, though.  And I've got to look after code which replaces that ugly-gram with '`VOID`' instead; it maps to '`(void)`' cast with Standard C compilers (all C compilers these days), but originated in the days before they were standard and then did things with assigning the result to a file static variable ('`#define VOID _void_ =`' or thereabouts).  Aaah; the memories, and the hoops that had to be jumped through.