# How to enforce the usage of return values in C

Tags: c, gcc

I'm searching for a compiler flag for gcc and if possible for clang and the Microsoft compilers as well, that triggers a warning (error with `-Werror`) if a non-void function is called without using the return value like this:

```
int test() {
    return 4;
}

int main(void) {
    test(); //should trigger a warning
    int number = test(); //shouldn't trigger the warning
    return 0;
}
```

If there is no such compiler flag, maybe some way to tell the clang static analyzer to complain about it.

**EDIT:** To clarify my original question: I actually meant using the return value, not only assigning it.

Comment: Note - Use `int main (void)` instead of `void`. .

Comment: That would cause lots of unnecessary warnings. For instance, every call to `printf()` would generate a complaint -- they return the number of characters printed, but no one really cares.

Comment: @Barmar, I could see where this might be handy for non-library functions though. When I add a return value to a previously void function, I have to change the rest of the signature just to hunt down all the places that use it.

Comment: Or you could use `grep`, or the IDE's built-in search facilities, like "where used".

Comment: There's a list of all GCC warning options here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to raise warning if return value is disregarded - gcc or static code check?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042780/how-to-raise-warning-if-return-value-is-disregarded-gcc-or-static-code-check)

Comment: @Andreas This question is related, but slightly different.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I never used it myself (*do you **really** need it?*), you can try

- defining the function with `warn_unused_result` attribute
- enabling `-Wunused-result` flag with `gcc`.

This will tell you about any unused value from the function return.

---

In case, any doubts, <kbd>[SEE IT LIVE](http://rextester.com/RMXUO96233)</kbd> or <kbd>[SEE IT LIVE AGAIN](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22JYOwLgBA%2BlCGZgE7AEYFcwFMYQBS4HdZEQo0Q0BnTAEykU0rQBswBKNiAM1wDcB7YDU4BvCAzBoSEAKwBuCAF8AUMtCQAtrFC42ykcohHuuuYYjmj6iAHMIAXhNszKoA%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g510%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O3%20-x%20c%20-std%3Dc11%20-pedantic%20-Wall%20-Wextra%22%7D%5D%7D)</kbd> <sup>Thanks to [M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m) for the link in the comment</sup>

Or:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int func1(void) __attribute__((warn_unused_result));
extern int func2(void);

int main(void)
{
    func1();
    int rc1 = func1();
    int rc2 = func1();
    func2();
    printf("%d\n", rc1);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation (GCC 5.1.0 on Mac OS X 10.10.5):

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c warn.c
warn.c: In function ‘main’:
warn.c:10:9: error: unused variable ‘rc2’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
     int rc2 = func1();
         ^
warn.c:8:5: error: ignoring return value of ‘func1’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Werror=unused-result]
     func1();
     ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

Comment: @Andreas: What makes you think that?

Comment: This will warn if he assigns the result to a variable but doesn't use the variable. He wants a warning for when he doesn't assign the result to a variable.

Comment: @Barmar: are you sure?  The 'variable set but not used' warning is separate, I think.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler With OP's code, I do not get a warning even with `-Wunused-result` (gcc 4.8.4)

Comment: @M.M I was in the process of doing the same. Thanks Much, I'll add your link too in my answer. :)

Comment: Perfect, setting the attribute on a per function basis is even better than complaining about every unused result.

Comment: @FSMaxB Yes, indeed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Some static code analyzers like [splint](http://www.splint.org/) can check for these kind of things:

```
$ splint check.c
Splint 3.1.2 --- 03 May 2009

check.c: (in function main)
check.c:6:5: Return value (type int) ignored: test()
  Result returned by function call is not used. If this is intended, can cast
  result to (void) to eliminate message. (Use -retvalint to inhibit warning)
```

Unlike @Sourav's answer, this does not require a specific `__attribute__` annotation on the target function, but on the other hand possibly emits many warnings. Its usually possible to suppress the warnings for specific functions or function calls by using annotations (like `/*@alt void@*/`).