# In C++ force all calls to either check the result or explicitly ignore it. Using VS

Tags: c++, static-analysis, lint

One common error in C++ is forgetting to look at the return value of a function. something like that:

```
void func() {
    SetEvent(some_handle);
}
```

Is there a way (using some static analyzer maybe?) to find all of these occurrences?

I want to force my code to either look at the result of all non-void functions, or explicitly ignore it like that:

```
void func() {
    (void)SetEvent(some_handle);
}
```

Something like defining all of the functions as [[nodiscard]] or as x__warn_unused_result__.

I'm using VS, but a good static-analyzer is good too.

Comment: Throw an exception.   That forces the caller (or, at minimum, some function in the call stack) to catch the exception, as the program will terminate otherwise.

Comment: @Peter Throwing an exception from the function only to make sure the caller doesn't discard the value? That sounds fishy.

Comment: OP, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042780/how-to-raise-warning-if-return-value-is-disregarded-gcc-or-static-code-check, specifically http://stackoverflow.com/a/2043261/1870760 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2042785/1870760

Comment: @Bill Gates - expecting to force the caller to check the return value from a function is also fishy.

Comment: From C++17, there is attribute `nodiscard`, see [attribute](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes)

Comment: If you are using gcc, there is an option for it `-Wunused-result`

Comment: @Danh - the attribute `nodiscard` is a suggestion to the compiler to issue a warning.   I would not necessarily describe that as forcing use of the return value (unless the compiler does actually issue a warning, and is configured to treat warnings as compilation errors).  Same for gcc's `-Wunused-result`.