# Ways to specify [[nodiscard]] before C++17

Tags: c++, nodiscard

I need the semantics of the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute in a non-C++17  codebase. I guess there are compiler dependent ways of achieving this before C++17. Does anyone know these? I am interested in the ones for clang,gcc, and MSVC.

Comment: What semantics? All nodiscard does is say "hey, if this return value is discarded you should probably issue a warning".

Comment: @Cubic: Exactly this!

Comment: A good place to look would be the compiler documentation.

Comment: GCC can use `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))`.

Comment: [strongly related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2042780/1708801)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- GCC/Clang: `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))`
- MSVC: `_Check_return_` for `_MSC_VER >= 1700` (Visual Studio 2012)

Comment: More recently, `[[gnu::warn_unused_result]]`.