# static library compatibilty for multiple c++ versions

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I'm making a library that supports multiple c++ versions (14/17/20) using the `__cplusplus` macro. For example I'd like to use the nodiscard and optional from cpp20 but still be compatible with cpp14. 
Obviously when compiling it to a .lib the c++ version will be set to the original version and not the version of the project using the library.

So my question regarding the best approach

- should I create multiple .lib files for the different c++ versions
- or more sensibly, should I create a header only library

The second option is naturally more appealing, yet I find the combination declaration + implementation in the same file a little verbose.

Are there any other ways of handling this? 
Would a DLL be better in this case?

Comment: For libraries that are amenable to be represented as header-only libraries, I like that approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nodiscard` and `std::optional` are C++17 not C++20 as you stated.  I would seriously suggest that you drop support for C++14 and move on with your life.  But if you can't do that, you can make your own wrapper macro for `nodiscard` which uses the older approaches where required: [Ways to specify [[nodiscard]] before C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190740/ways-to-specify-nodiscard-before-c17)

For `std::optional` if you need C++14 support, just don't use `std::optional` in your API, keep it as an internal implementation detail.  It's very likely that `std::optional` is a header-only feature on the systems where you build, so as long as it's not part of your public API your users probably won't notice.