# Compiler option to catch unassigned r-values

Tags: c++, gcc, return-value, compiler-warnings

Rather embarrassingly, I wrote something like the following (sanitised):

```
vector_item next()
{
    if (this->it == this->myVector.end()){
        this->it == this->myVector.begin();
    }
    return *(this->it++);
}
```

The obvious error is, well, obvious. It did however take a short while to track down.

No compiler warnings were generated for this, but should one have been? There is an unused r-value created right here (and not say, an unused return value from a function that was called for its side effects), which seems to me to be an indicator of there being something amiss with the code.

Compiled with `g++ -Wall -Wextra`. (GCC 4.8.3)

I know about `-Wunused-result` but that doesn't apply here.

Comment: compiler version?

Comment: Unused return value are usual: you don't write `static_cast<void>(std::cout << "hi");`.

Comment: if `vector::iterator` is a class, then `operator ==` is not the built-in and is a regular function which might have side effect.

Comment: @Jarod42: indeed. For example using VS2013, it only complains if they are built in types (C4553). Both assignment operator as begin() can have side effects.

Comment: @Jarod42 hmm, according to the answers, clang takes it as a standard equality comparison.

Comment: I thought that `-Wunused-value` might help (it does catch statements such as `3 == 4;`) but was surprised to find it doesn't.  BTW, that sample is woefully incomplete; try `#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    auto it = v.begin();
    if (it == v.end()) {
        it == v.begin();
    }
    return it == v.end();
}` instead.

Comment: @TobySpeight I didn't intend for it to be runnable, just an illustration of usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> No compiler warnings were generated for this, but should one have been?

I can't think of anything I've read in the standard that demands a warning here.

However, the clang dev team seem to think it warrants one:

```
18 : <source>:18:18: warning: equality comparison result unused [-Wunused-comparison]
        this->it == this->myVector.begin();
        ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
18 : <source>:18:18: note: use '=' to turn this equality comparison into an assignment
        this->it == this->myVector.begin();
                 ^~
                 =
1 warning generated.
```

My first thoughts are that it's a QoI issue in gcc. Might be worth raising it as an issue.

I am fortunate in that our software is compiled for mac (clang), linux (gcc) and windows (msvc) so standards infringements and edge cases are caught early.

Might be an idea to recompile your code on another compiler before going on a bug hunt now and again - it helps me.

Comment: Ah great, because when I wrote my answer I was afraid of missing something in the standard, happy to see that we agree.

Comment: _"Might be worth raising it as an issue"_ Having looked (now I know the clang flag, I've found [these](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62182) two [bugs](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53598) so it seems that it is in the system.

Answer (score 4):

> No compiler warnings were generated for this, but should one have been?

There is nothing declared in the Standard that should make GCC generate a warning for that case.

You could extend `begin()`, by marking it as `WARN_UNUSED`, where first you would have define:

```
#define WARN_UNUSED __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042780/how-to-raise-warning-if-return-value-is-disregarded), but this of course it's not exactly you are looking for, but it's something. I can't find any option of GCC to generate a warning in your case.

It is a known [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62182) though, but [hasn't implemented](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53598) the functionality you are looking for, at least until 2017-07-21.

---

However, clang 6.0.0 issues a warning for this, (even if `Wall` and `Wextra` flags are not used):

```
prog.cc:11:18: warning: equality comparison result unused [-Wunused-comparison]
        this->it == this->myVector.begin();
        ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:11:18: note: use '=' to turn this equality comparison into an assignment
        this->it == this->myVector.begin();
                 ^~
                 =
1 warning generated.
```

Moreover, zapcc 1.0.1 issues a warning as well (again even without the warning flags):

```
/home/jail/prog.cc:11:18: warning: equality comparison result unused [-Wunused-comparison]
        this->it == this->myVector.begin();
        ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/jail/prog.cc:11:18: note: use '=' to turn this equality comparison into an assignment
        this->it == this->myVector.begin();
                 ^~
                 =
1 warning generated.
```

View it yourself in [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/), if you like.